# How to automatically initialize Eigen matrices with signaling NaNs?

Tags: c++, initialization, nan, eigen

I'd like to catch use of uninitialized values in Eigen matrices in my project. In the [documentation](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicPreprocessorDirectives.html) I've found a useful definition I can use: `EIGEN_INITIALIZE_MATRICES_BY_NAN`. This is already better than nothing, but is still not good enough: as I can grep Eigen's source, they explicitly initialize by *quiet* NaN by using `std::numeric_limits<Scalar>::quiet_NaN()`.

I'd rather have the program get an FPU exception (which can be made to trap) on such events instead of silently propagating the NaN value. I've thought of doing a `#define quiet_NaN signaling_NaN` before including any Eigen header and `#undef quiet_NaN` afterwards, but after looking at the sources I've found that they do include a bunch of system headers, which will most likely work incorrectly with such a `#define`.

Is there a better way to automatically initialize the matrices with signaling NaNs than to edit Eigen sources?

Comment: What about using a memory debugger tool like [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)?

Comment: @ggael it's unacceptably slow for my application, while FPU traps are essentially free.